# ValueError: Could not reserve memory block

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I setup Superset on AWS and was trying to load the data examples when I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 10, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/cli.py", line 95, in load_examples
    data.load_world_bank_health_n_pop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/superset/data/__init__.py", line 174, in load_world_bank_health_n_pop
    pdf = pd.read_json(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 211, in read_json
    date_unit).parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 279, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 496, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
ValueError: Could not reserve memory block
```

how can I solve this memory limit?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem (at 512M AWS) and solved via adding swap.

Ref: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/1986#issuecomment-279919030

```
fallocate -l 1G /swapfile  
chmod 600 /swapfile  
mkswap /swapfile  
swapon /swapfile  
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak  
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```